# Minimizing a multivariable function of loop iterations

Tags: python, arrays, loops, wolfram-mathematica, minimization

I'm trying to minimize a function `f` of ~80 variables stored in an `array`. The function is defined by two nested loops: the outer one indexes `array` by `i`, while the inner loop is performed `array[i]` times and adds the result of a computation to a running total. The computation depends on some conditions `x` and `y` and changes slightly every time it's performed, which is why I need the loop structure. Here is a minimal working example in Python:

```
def f[array]:
    total = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(array[i]):
            result = 2*x + y
            total = total + result
            x = x+1
        x = 0
        y = y+1
    return total
```

So for instance, `print f([2,1])` returns 3, since [(2*0) + 0] + [(2*1) + 0] + [(2*0) + 1] = 0+2+1 = 3.

I want to find the entries of `array` that minimize the value of `f`. However, when I tell (e.g.) Mathematica to minimize `f([x1, x2, ..., x80])` and spit out the minimizer `array`, the program complains because it can't perform the loops defining `f` an indeterminate number of times.

In light of this, my question is the following:

> How do I minimize a multivariate function whose parameters describe the number of times a given loop is to be iterated?

I had originally tried to implement this in Mathematica, but found that I could not define `f` by the procedure above. The best I could do is tell Mathematica to perform the loops above, then define `f[array_] := total` after `total` had been computed. When I ran my code, Mathematica naturally claimed that it could not evaluate `f`, throwing an error even before it executed my command to `NMinimize[{f[array] array ϵ Integers}, array]`. The fact that Mathematica is trying to evaluate `f` before it is called in `NMinimize` indicates that I don't quite understand how functions work in Mathematica. Any help in untangling this situation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First, you could have a look at [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization) Wikipedia page about function optimization. Given that you can't differentiate the function, a whole lot of possible techniques turn out to be inapplicable, which is a pity.

Comment: If you could create a concrete example problem that is perhaps ten or twenty times simpler than your real problem, but which keeps the essential character of your problem, and you could edit your post to include the complete definition and details of the sample problem then someone might be able to scrape your example into their notebook, adjust the notation and definition a little and show one or two ways to minimize the example. Then you might be able to map that technique back to your real problem.

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, the integer constraints eliminate many numerical methods, but my concern is more generally about how to get a program to execute more or less _any_ function call on `f`, since its parameters become variable numbers of loop iterations.

Comment: @Bill I have edited my post to include a minimal working example. My real problem is a hefty optimization in atomic physics that involves minimizing an integrated squared error of magnetic fields due to complicated arrangements of coils--the above code is really just the bare bones of what I need to understand.

Comment: This function is minimized trivially when all entries of `array` are 0. The inner loop never executes and 0 is returned. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry- I should mention that the entries of `array` should be integers greater than or equal to 1. Even so, it doesn't really matter what `result` is; in reality, the function could be arbitrarily complicated. My issue is still with the implementation of an actual minimization algorithm that takes as input the various numbers of iterations of the inner loop in `array`.

Comment: you should decide what language you are interested in and make the question more specific.

Comment: Could give another example that's more like the problem you're trying to solve? From your description and example it seems like the optimal solution would be an array of 1s.

Answer (score 2):

As written your function has an analytical minimum and there is no need for numerical optimization. Unfortunately, StackOverflow won't let me show the mathematics of it (if you ask it on MathExchange I can provide a derivation), but given an array `A = [a0 a1 ... an]` where each `ai` is a positive integer, and an array `Y = [0 1 ... n]` the function you posted reduces to the following matrix multiplication `A * (A - 1 + Y)'` where `'` denotes a matrix transpose and `*` denotes matrix multiplication. So, trivially, the function is minimized when each `ai` is minimized. So, if this is part of a larger optimization, your task should be focused on finding the minimum of each element of `A` if the elements themselves are constrained.